# Getting 404 on all pages when deploying Contentful + NextJS project in AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-amplify, next.js13, contentful

Getting 404 on all pages when deploying Contentful + NextJS project in AWS Amplify

https://github.com/imsraja/yes2cloud-blog is where the repo is stored.

Amplify successfully deployed but getting 404 on all pages. Followed the options in several stack overflow posts but none worked.

[image]

[image]

Appreciate any help here.

Comment: It was a trivial mistake from my side. I mispelled when dynamically writing the environment file`.env.production` in build settings